# Kubernetes installation problem

Tags: juju, kubernetes

I just installed Charmed Kubernetes using the quick start on a single systems using lxd. I have some services which are sitting in waiting status.

```
# juju status
Model Controller Cloud/Region Version SLA Timestamp
k8s-test my-cloud-controller localhost/localhost 2.6.6 unsupported 23:05:36Z


App Version Status Scale Charm Store Rev OS Notes
containerd active 5 containerd jujucharms 20 ubuntu
easyrsa 3.0.1 active 1 easyrsa jujucharms 270 ubuntu
etcd 3.2.10 active 3 etcd jujucharms 449 ubuntu
flannel 0.10.0 active 5 flannel jujucharms 438 ubuntu
kubeapi-load-balancer 1.14.0 active 1 kubeapi-load-balancer jujucharms 664 ubuntu exposed
kubernetes-master 1.15.2 waiting 2 kubernetes-master jujucharms 724 ubuntu
kubernetes-worker 1.15.2 active 3 kubernetes-worker jujucharms 571 ubuntu exposed


Unit Workload Agent Machine Public address Ports Message
easyrsa/0* active idle 0 10.15.77.181 Certificate Authority connected.
etcd/0 active idle 1 10.15.77.37 2379/tcp Healthy with 3 known peers
etcd/1* active idle 2 10.15.77.32 2379/tcp Healthy with 3 known peers
etcd/2 active idle 3 10.15.77.251 2379/tcp Healthy with 3 known peers
kubeapi-load-balancer/0* active idle 4 10.15.77.178 443/tcp Loadbalancer ready.
kubernetes-master/0 waiting idle 5 10.15.77.52 6443/tcp Waiting for 6 kube-system pods to start
containerd/4 active idle 10.15.77.52 Container runtime available.
flannel/4 active idle 10.15.77.52 Flannel subnet 10.1.92.1/24
kubernetes-master/1* waiting idle 6 10.15.77.76 6443/tcp Waiting for 6 kube-system pods to start
containerd/1 active idle 10.15.77.76 Container runtime available.
flannel/1 active idle 10.15.77.76 Flannel subnet 10.1.4.1/24
kubernetes-worker/0 active idle 7 10.15.77.70 80/tcp,443/tcp Kubernetes worker running.
containerd/2 active idle 10.15.77.70 Container runtime available.
flannel/2 active idle 10.15.77.70 Flannel subnet 10.1.35.1/24
kubernetes-worker/1* active idle 8 10.15.77.219 80/tcp,443/tcp Kubernetes worker running.
containerd/0* active idle 10.15.77.219 Container runtime available.
flannel/0* active idle 10.15.77.219 Flannel subnet 10.1.69.1/24
kubernetes-worker/2 active idle 9 10.15.77.119 80/tcp,443/tcp Kubernetes worker running.
containerd/3 active idle 10.15.77.119 Container runtime available.
flannel/3 active idle 10.15.77.119 Flannel subnet 10.1.50.1/24


Machine State DNS Inst id Series AZ Message
0 started 10.15.77.181 juju-59942b-0 bionic Running
1 started 10.15.77.37 juju-59942b-1 bionic Running
2 started 10.15.77.32 juju-59942b-2 bionic Running
3 started 10.15.77.251 juju-59942b-3 bionic Running
4 started 10.15.77.178 juju-59942b-4 bionic Running
5 started 10.15.77.52 juju-59942b-5 bionic Running
6 started 10.15.77.76 juju-59942b-6 bionic Running
7 started 10.15.77.70 juju-59942b-7 bionic Running
8 started 10.15.77.219 juju-59942b-8 bionic Running
9 started 10.15.77.119 juju-59942b-9 bionic Running
```

I am seeing these messages in the logs:

```
# juju debug-log -m k8s-test -n 20

unit-kubernetes-worker-2: 23:24:33 INFO unit.kubernetes-worker/2.juju-log Failed to apply label juju-application=kubernetes-worker. Will retry.
unit-kubernetes-worker-1: 23:24:33 DEBUG unit.kubernetes-worker/1.update-status Error from server (NotFound): nodes "juju-59942b-8" not found
unit-kubernetes-worker-1: 23:24:33 INFO unit.kubernetes-worker/1.juju-log Failed to apply label juju-application=kubernetes-worker. Will retry.
unit-kubernetes-worker-0: 23:24:33 DEBUG unit.kubernetes-worker/0.update-status Error from server (NotFound): nodes "juju-59942b-7" not found
unit-kubernetes-worker-0: 23:24:33 INFO unit.kubernetes-worker/0.juju-log Failed to apply label juju-application=kubernetes-worker. Will retry.
unit-kubernetes-worker-2: 23:24:34 DEBUG unit.kubernetes-worker/2.update-status Error from server (NotFound): nodes "juju-59942b-9" not found
unit-kubernetes-worker-2: 23:24:34 INFO unit.kubernetes-worker/2.juju-log Failed to apply label juju-application=kubernetes-worker. Will retry.
```

Any ideas of what is going on here?

Comment: Can you please tell us how did you install it, please? Also, Please review this answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/1147622/juju-charmed-kubernetes-what-are-minimal-hardware-requirements/1160202#1160202

Comment: Here is what I had done:

Comment: Here is what I had done:
<code>
sudo snap install lxd
/snap/bin/lxd.migrate
/snap/bin/lxd init
Name of the storage backend to use (btrfs, ceph, cephfs, dir, lvm, zfs) [default=zfs]: dir
What IPv6 address should be used? (CIDR subnet notation, “auto” or “none”) [default=auto]: none
juju bootstrap localhost my-cloud-controller
juju add-model k8s-test
juju deploy charmed-kubernetes
</code>

Comment: I just followed the guide in the above link and I am still getting some things not starting.

I am seeing a different error message though:

`machine-9: 09:23:53 ERROR juju.worker.dependency "broker-tracker" manifold worker returned unexpected error: cannot create instance broker: creating LXD container manager: Get http://unix.socket/1.0: dial unix /var/lib/lxd/unix.socket: connect: connection refused`

That looks like the wrong path, /var/lib/lxd/unix.socket doesn’t exist, it should be /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/unix.socket. I’m not sure where to change that.

Comment: After more testing I think this might be an issue with the current version of charmed kubernetes. If I use "juju deploy charmed-kubernetes-124" instead of "juju deploy charmed-kubernetes-209" it works fine.

Comment: That's strange (but also good, I guess) that an older version of the charm works.